# Efficiently doing interrow calculations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
Date          A B C D
2015-08-07    1 2 4 5
2015-08-06    5 6 2 5
2015-08-05    9 6 3 0
...
2015-09-01    3 4 6 7
```

I need to generate a new dataframe where the row values become the day-on-day change from previous day.

```
Date         A  B  C D
2015-08-07  -4 -4  2 0   # 2015-08-07 data minus the 2015-08-06 data
2015-08-06  -4  0 -1 5
...
2015-09-02
```

I can do this with grotesque for-loops and nasty indexing hacks, but I am certain there will be more elegant ways to do this inside pandas (the equivalent of vectorization  versus for-loops). Can anyone suggest the right pandas approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas.DataFrame.diff) and pass `-1` to shift upwards a single period:

```
In [69]:
df.diff(-1)
Out[69]:
      Date   A   B   C   D
0   1 days  -4  -4   2   0
1   1 days  -4   0  -1   5
2 -27 days   6   2  -3  -7
3      NaT NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Also you should almost never need to iterate row-wise so avoid using `for` loops, `apply`, `iterrows` etc...

Comment: briliant. Love that it reduces to a single line. thanks